# How to get elements from an array based on condition in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo-3.x

I am the beginner in MongoDB & Here is my sample doc given below :

```
{
"plan_id" : "100",
"schedule_plan_list" : [ 
    {
        "date" : "01-05-2020",
        "time" : "9:00AM -10:00AM"
    }, 
    {
        "date" : "02-05-2020",
        "time" : "10:00AM -11:00AM"
    }, 
    {
        "date" : "03-05-2020",
        "time" : "9:00AM -10:00AM"
    }, 
    {
        "date" : "04-05-2020",
        "time" : "9:30AM -10:30AM"
    }, 
    {
        "date" : "05-05-2020",
        "time" : "9:00AM -10:00AM"
    }, 
    {
        "date" : "06-05-2020",
        "time" : "9:00AM -10:00AM"
    }, 
    {
        "date" : "07-05-2020",
        "time" : "9:30AM -10:30AM"
    }, 
    {
        "date" : "08-05-2020",
        "time" : "4:00PM -5:00PM"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get **next 5 elements ** based on given date is **"02-05-2020"**

My given query fetch only match "02-05-2020"  but I want **"02-05-2020","03-05-2020",.."06-05-2020"**

```
 db.getCollection('schedule_plans').find({"plan_id" : "100"},{_id:0,"schedule_plan_list": { "$elemMatch": { "date" : "02-05-2020"}}})
```

so anyone help me to solve this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ $match: { "plan_id": "100" } },
/** You can re-create `schedule_plan_list` field with condition applied & slice the new array to keep required no.of elements in array */
{
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    "schedule_plan_list": {
      $slice: [
        {
          $filter: { input: "$schedule_plan_list", cond: { $gte: [ "$$this.date", "02-05-2020" ] } }
        },
        5
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ziJZg6plR9h)

**Ref :** [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)